# Permanently disable airplane mode gnome 3.2

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3, ethernet

I have a computer running centOS 7 and Gnome 3.2 and everytime the computer boots it boots with airplane mode enabled and the ethernet interface disabled. I've been looking for a solution but I cannot find a proper way to disable it. I've noticed that both the Airplane mode and the ethernet interfaced can be enabled at the same time. Basically what I want is for my computer to be connected to the internet as soon as it boots. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helps in debian `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active false`

Comment: Yes, it does, but unfortunately it also disables the GNOME3 Bluetooth controls. BT _is_ working, but the GNOME3 UI gets disabled this way.